# Does this series with binomial coefficient converge (absolutely)?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

How do I find out if this series converges (absolutely)?

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom {2k}k * 5 ^{-k} $$

We have the binomial coefficient there and I was wondering if one can actually cancel the k! in the numerator  ?

[image]

Regarding the denominator, it 
$$5^{-k} = (1/5^k)$$  converges as it is getting bigger and bigger.

Comment: Have you tried the ratio test ?

Comment: By Stirling's approximation, we can compare this sum to $\sum \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}(4/5)^n$

Comment: According to Wolframalpha, it converges to $\sqrt{5}-1$.

Comment: Note that $$\binom{2k}{k}=\frac{(2k)!}{k!\cdot k!}=\frac{(2k)!}{(k!)^2}$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that the series with positive terms therefore it doesn't make sense talk about absolute convergence.

We can use that by [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient#Bounds_and_asymptotic_formulas)

$$\binom {2k}k\sim \frac{4^k}{\sqrt{\pi k}}$$

therefore

$$\binom {2k}k \cdot 5 ^{-k}\sim \frac{4^k}{5^k\sqrt{\pi k}}$$

from which we can conclude by limit comparison test.

As a simpler alternative by [ratio test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test)

$$\frac{\binom {2k+2}{k+1} \frac1{5 ^{k+1}}}{\binom {2k}{k} \frac1{5 ^{k}}}=\frac15 \frac{(2k+2)!(k!)^2}{[(k+1)!]^2(2k)!}=\frac15 \frac{(2k+2)(2k+1)}{(k+1)^2}\to \frac45$$

Comment: Hi, first of all: Thanks. Can you maybe enhance that last part a bit? I don't understand how you got from (2k+2)!(k!)^2 to (2k+2)(2k+1)

Comment: @JavaTeachMe2018 We have $$(2k+2)!=(2k+2)(2k+1)(2k)!$$ and the $(2k)!$ terms cancels out with the term at the denominator. Similarly $$[(k+1)!]^2= [(k+1)\cdot k!]^2=(k+1)^2\cdot (k!)^2$$

Comment: Ok, but isn't $$(k!)^2)$$ missing in the denominator then? We've cancelled out the $$(2k)!$$, but you showed me that $$[(k+1)!]^2$$ equals $$(k+1)^2 * (k!)^2$$

Comment: We have that $$\frac{(2k+2)!(k!)^2}{[(k+1)!]^2(2k)!}= \frac{(2k+2)(2k+1)(2k)!(k!)^2}{(k+1)^2(k!)^2(2k)!}= \frac{(2k+2)(2k+1)}{(k+1)^2}$$

Comment: Thanks, now I get it :)

Comment: @JavaTeachMe2018 Well done! You are welcome, Bye!

Answer (score 5):

The generating function for the [central binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_binomial_coefficient#Properties) is well known :
$$\tag{1}\frac 1{\sqrt{1-4x}}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom {2k}k\, x^k$$
(you may prove it using the Taylor series for $\,(1-4x)^{-1/2}\;$)

as well as the asymptotic expression for the binomial coefficients :
(for example using Stirling as done by gimusi)
$$\tag{2}{2k \choose k} \sim \frac{4^k}{\sqrt{\pi k}}$$

so that $(1)$ will converge for $\;x< \dfrac 14$.

For $x=\dfrac 15$ the series becomes $\;\displaystyle\frac 1{\sqrt{1-\frac 45}}=\sqrt{5}$